# connect direct File (.cvs) file copy from Unix to HP Non stop

Tags: unix, hp-nonstop

I am trying to copy a file from Unix to HP Non stop server through Connect Direct. But I am unable to copy the file. Following is what I am intending to do.
         Copy a cvs file from Unix to Hp Non stop everyday.
         The file will be replaced daily. 
         If the file is not present already should be created at the destination   node automatically.
         The file is transferred in Binary format.

Below is the copy script.

```
     direct  << EOJ
                submit maxdelay=0 test   process     snode=HPNSTP
                        step01   copy from      (
                            file=/file/to/path/file.cvs -- unix server
                            pnode
                            sysopts=":datatype=binary:"

                            )
                    to      (
                            dsn=$VOL.SUBVOL.FILEDUMMY
                            snode
                            sysopts="SET XLATE OFF,EXT(500,500),MAXEXTENTS 500"
                            disp=RPL,,DELETE
                            )
                pend;
                    a= return $?
                    EOJ
                    if ($a -gt 0)
                    then
                    echo "Copy successful"
                    else
                    echo "Copy failed"
                    fi
```

I am getting a **|MSGI=SFLH913I|MSST=illegal filename specification -> &FILE** error when i try to copy the file.

I am not familiar with HP Non stop file system. Can someone please tell what is wrong with the scripts or should I have to add other params.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When transferring file from unix to Tandem, destination file should be enclosed within `' '`

```
dsn='$VOL.SUBVOL.FILEDUMMY'
```